# Best practice for sensor data over MQTT

Tags: mqtt, sensors, measurement

Currently I am using the following approach to send sensor data:

Use case send outside temperature of 23.5 °C.

- topic: weather/outside/temperature
- content: 23.5

It is quite easy to send or consume such a message but for the receiver it is difficult to determine the unit of the content.

I have also seen the approach to send "23.5 °C" as content but then it is more difficult to parse.

I can also imagine using a part of the topic name for the unit.

So my question is: What are best practices to send scalar values with a unit in such a way that it is possible to reason about the unit in a automated way but also make it easy to send/receive the data. Are there maybe even standards for this?

Comment: Send it as JSON?  `{ value: 23.5, unit: "C" }`

Comment: I initially discarded json as it is typically not supported on embedded systems .. but at least on the sender side it is quite easy to create a json  string by hand. On the receiver side I often use Node Red which works well with json, so this could be a solution. I am still interested if there maybe is some standard.

Comment: To my knowledge, JSON is the only payload "standard" in use with MQTT.  For instance, IBM's Watson uses JSON for MQTT payloads that aren't simply binary data (like an image).  One could argue that if IBM is doing it, it could be considered a "standard".

Comment: The problem here is that "standard" implies a published document that defines and mandates specific practices, formats, encodings, etc.  No such standard exists for MQTT payloads; in fact, the MQTT specification leaves this completely open.  So, the best answer you'll find is to look at what the big companies do with MQTT payloads.  Azure IoT treats them strictly as binary data, while Watson uses JSON or binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{value:23.5, unit:"C"} can be used. I couldn't find any best practises for payloads.